# Text control that render html

Tags: windows-phone, richtextbox, c1richtextbox

Does anyone know a Windows Phone textbox control that binds to HTML property? I've used C1RichTextBox and it does the job but it's too damn slow! Please help.

Comment: What is too slow? I'm assuming time to render but can you confirm? Also, how complex is the HTML you want to show? Can you share an example?

Comment: Do you mean textbox (which enables editing) or a textBLOCK (which just displays text)?

Comment: @MattLacey We need textblock. We need this just to display text in this format: ![CDATA[Lorem <b>ipsum</b> bla bla]]>

Answer (score 1):

The [control from ComponentOne](https://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioWindowsPhone/) is the only one [I'm aware of](http://blog.mrlacey.co.uk/2013/06/comparing-3rd-party-windows-phone.html).

Where I've had to display HTML content in the past I've used one of the following two approaches.

1. Display the content in a WebBrowser control.
2. Manually parse the HTML and convert it into XAML controls.

The first option is appropriate when there is large amount of HTML to parse and when it is likely to vary greatly. (i.e. you can't be sure you'll only get a certain set of tags being used.)
If using the second option, be sure to consider using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to help tidy up the HTML before parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is to put RichTextBox into a ScrollViewer to take advantage of the hardware accelerated control.

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <c1:C1RichTextBox Height="1000" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: How does this help with the speed of the C1RichTextBox? Putting something in a ScrollViewer won't improve the performance of the behaviour of the control. Also, What do you mean by "hardware accelerated"? Do you mean the GPU?